# Inserting data into SQL Server from a form via nodejs in Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: sql, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding and I'm trying to figure out how to add the user input from a registration form into SQL Server using nodeJs in Visual Studio Code.

I have an existing database on Azure I have connected to but not sure of what I need to say to ensure the user's input gets saved to the database.

This is what I have so far but when I click register on the application it appears to just get stuck loading... is the function throwing things off? How do I get my data saved to the database? I hope this info is enough!

Database config:

```
   const dbConn = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config);
   
   // Connect to SQL
   dbConn.connect(function(err) {
       if(err) {
           return err;
       }
   });

// Register Handle
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    var newUsers = {
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        mobile: req.body.mobile,
        password: req.body.password,
        /*confirmpassword: req.body.confirmpassword*/
    };

    function CreateNewUser (newUsers) {
        var sqlQuery ="INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Username, Email, MobileNumber, UserPassword) VALUES ('firstname', 'lastname', 'username', '.email', 'mobile', 'password')";

        console.log(newUsers);
        res.send("Welcome to Summit!");

        res.redirect('/users/signin');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have created the query but aren't executing it
- neither you are invoking the createNewUser function

Comment: Thank you, could you describe what that would look like?

Comment: what package you are using for DB connectivity ?

Comment: Node js, I installed the mssql package